# Old style join in Oracle SQL query

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, left-join, oracle-sqldeveloper

I know this syntax .i know its quite old but I am tuning an old query. I know below syntax

`emp.deptno(+)=dept.deptno;` this is `right outer join.`

But I am not able to understand meaning of below.

`AND TRUNC(SYSDATE) BETWEEN ptm.effective_start_date (+) AND ptm.effective_end_date (+)`

how (+) is getting used in between. what is the meaning of it?

Comment: Read the manual for functionality you are using. "apply the outer join operator (+) to all columns of B in the join condition in the WHERE clause"

Answer (score 2):

Let examine the followign query

```
select tab1.id, tab2.start_date, tab2.end_date
from  tab1,
tab2
where tab1.id = tab2.id(+) and
sysdate between tab2.start_date(+) and tab2.end_date(+)
```

The ANSI equivalent is

```
select tab1.id, tab2.start_date, tab2.end_date
from  tab1 
left outer join tab2
on tab1.id = tab2.id and
sysdate between tab2.start_date  and tab2.end_date
```

The meaning is *join on `ID` and constraint the `start_date` and `end_date`* but is there is no match in the second table, do not suppress the row from the first table.

Sample data and the result

```
select * from tab1;

        ID
----------
         1
         2

 select * from tab2;

        ID START_DATE          END_DATE           
---------- ------------------- -------------------
         1 01.01.2020 00:00:00 31.12.2020 00:00:00
```

the join returns

```
        ID START_DATE          END_DATE           
---------- ------------------- -------------------
         1 01.01.2020 00:00:00 31.12.2020 00:00:00
         2
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from good explanation in other answers, there is a golden rule when you use the old syntax.

Rule:

- always use the `(+)` sign with outer joined table's column in `WHERE` clause if any condition is checking value against any constant/sys values.

So it will go like this:

```
Select * from t1 , t2
 Where t1.col = t2.col(+) -- this represent outer join
   And t1.other_col = sysdate -- or some constant -- this is ok as this is main table in join
   And t2.other_col(+) = sysdate -- or some constant -- (+) is needed as it is outer joined table
                                 -- if you will omit (+) here, join will be converted to inner join
```